# Would Patindex or another Sql function be best for below?

Tags: sql, ssis, ssms

Currently working on taking a field that has numbers and letters as shown below. I need to get the number for 1 field, and the letters for another field. Would patindex be best?

Would need numbers only: there is a space between

```
2777 abcdef
8000080 abcdef
```

i tried trim, and have looked for other options but have not found a example.

Comment: SSMS is just an IDE-like application that is used with several products such as (but not limited to) SQL Server, Azure SQL Edge and Azure Synapse. SSMS is likely irrelevant to the question here. What product are you actually using for your data engine?

Comment: `LEFT`/`STUFF` and `CHARINDEX` would make more sense, if the values are always in the format `<Integer Value> <String Value>`

Comment: What does SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) have to do with the problem? Do we actually need to do this in an SSIS expression within a data flow or something..?

Comment: Hey Thom i am pulling the data from txt file into ssis, and then putting into a table. prob nothing but i am just specifying a few tags

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.  Since there are only 2 fields to parse, use this parsename() trick.  The with statement just sets up test data.

```
with tbl(id, str) as (
  select 1, '2777 abcdef' union all
  select 2, '8000080 abcdef'
)
SELECT id, PARSENAME(REPLACE(str , ' ' , '.'),2) as col1,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(str , ' ' , '.'),1) as col2
FROM tbl;

id  col1    col2
1   2777    abcdef
2   8000080 abcdef
```

Comment: Thanks for the example Gary!